# Duplicate active meta posts and some other bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, ajax

Since a few days, my error console is flooded with some messages <sup>[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXXS8.png)</sup>

I didn't pay attention to these, until I saw some weird behaviour (**The previously mentioned errors might or might not be related to the spotted bugs.**):

1. *Always reproducible* On Meta, active posts are automatically looked up. When a post has a modification, a boxed number appears before the **active** tab (similar to the box at **featured**).
   After clicking on this box, the updated question is added.. ..without removing the previous one:
   [image]
2. *Occurred only once, so far* The inbox notification is highlighted - I have *zero* new messages!
   [image: (0) new messages]

   On click, the following page is requested: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/undefined/genuwine?callback=jQuery1710849796595935935_1328957573777&_=1328958526596.
   This request fails, and the following shows up:
   [image: An error occurred while loading - please try again.]
3. *Always reproducible* After closing the box, the box flashes on hover. When I move away the cursor after clicking, the box does not re-appear again after flashing.

### Possibly relevant information

- Browser: Firefox 10.0, without any conflicting add-ons (NoScript, Firebug, Stylish, Greasemonkey).
- I have usually multiple meta tabs open at a time.

All of these bugs are also observed in Opera 11.61, with only one active meta window.

Comment: @Mat Opera 11 is also supported, according to that page. I do *also* experience these bugs in Opera 11.61 (VirtualBox Puppy Linux, but OS should not matter).

Comment: @Mat SE always supports the latest stable version of each browser (as you can see in that question), so it's the question that needs updating (Firefox 10 is stable right now)

Comment: Can anyone confirm my bug? To reproduce, just open meta's front page, and wait until `active` is highlighted. Then click on it. For the other bug, wait until an inbox notification is received (on meta). Then, click on it, and click away. Then click on the StackExchange thing again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback - we are currently testing a few new features on meta only to support real time updates.  I have disabled real time inbox notifications for the moment and will push a fix for both the global inbox and the active tab dupes a bit later today.

Comment: I am interested in your ideas and would like to subscribe to your newsletter.